# Is there a free/pay web service that I can query to get MLS data?

Tags: xml, web-services

Given an [MLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_Listing_Service)#, I'd like to get an XML document with details about the listing, like address, price and such. Not a NAR or CREA member. Mostly interested in North American rental property listing data.

Comment: The MLS is the Multiple Listing Service, the "encyclopedia," so to speak, of currently-for-sale homes in the United States and, I believe, Canada.

Comment: while this is a fairly off-topic question, i'm just putting in my (much later) opinion to re-open. MLS APIs are especially troublesome, not like most APIs we work wtih. Many devs have no idea where to start. Even if the question were to be horrendously mangled, a more robust answer would be really useful to this site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're an NAR member, you can utilize their Internet Data Exchange (IDX) system, but it isn't available to non-members.

Comment: Do you have any updates about this topic?

Comment: @BenjaminBakhshi do you find somtehing about this topic

Comment: @EmilioGort did anyone find any info on this topic, whether free or reasonably paid, that has aggregated listings? for the truly desperate, i'll drop that CoreLogic offers quite a bit and aggressively goes after competition so i'm not super hopeful but always looking

Comment: @GaretClaborn the only way i found to access to the mls was buying the access here http://www.miamirealtors.com/services/resources/rets because I'm in Miami. It has listings from USA, Canada, Part of Mexico and Europe

Answer (score 3):

The best free source at the moment is Oodle.com's API - http://developer.oodle.com/oodle-api.  It will give you both for sale and for rent homes.

You can see what their listings look like here: http://realestate.oodle.com/

The MLS' don't typically give their data out.   The big rental sites (rent.com, apartments.com, etc.) don't have an API, but do give out data feeds if you contact them and work out a business relationship with them.

Answer (score 1):

**Multiple Listing Service (MLS)** - a system in the USA and Canada for real estate

For mls.ca (Canadian system), here's an interesting perspective (*posted 2008-08-21*) on it's *availability* to the public:

[Canadian Realtor Data Cartel](http://www.guydavis.ca/log/view.jsp?id=1066) excerpt:

> Realtors as consultants would also mean they could relax their data cartel, also known as the Multiple Listings Service. This database of sale listings has two faces. Firstly, a private view for realtors only, which shows real-time listings with full details about the homes. The MLS also provides a public view of the data but listings there are time-delayed (often by days) and don't provide all useful details such as direction house is facing, wether the basement is developed, etc in a searchable format. Only recently, due to repeated better offerings that were sued out of existence by the cartel, has the MLS even added interactive maps. They still time-delay public listings and hide many useful details.