# Data Lookup Services

Tags: web-services

I am looking for a Data Look up Service, that I could send a real estate property address (street, city, state, zip) and get back information about this property (owners, mortgage, sq footage, rooms, etc)

Would any one know of an existing service like that, that could be used and an ASP.Net application?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well the type of service you are looking for is generally limited to Multiple Listing Service.  To be a member of an MLS you have to me a member of the NAR (National Association of Realtors).  Even then the type of service you are looking for (on demand lookup) is then available generally only to Designated Brokers (there is only one Designated Broker per Real Estate brokerage).  However you can sometimes find services that can provide MLS like lookups for you (check google etc) but you will likely have to pay.  It would probably interest you to check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130170/is-there-a-free-pay-web-service-that-i-can-query-to-get-mls-data).