# Creating a MLS function on a website

Tags: api, plugins

I am trying to develop a function on a real estate website that shows all of the listings in the local MLS.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a free API or plugin that could be used to accomplish this. I would prefer it if I was able to show all listings in the area and display them on the client's site.

Any suggestions / direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a free/pay web service that I can query to get MLS data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130170/is-there-a-free-pay-web-service-that-i-can-query-to-get-mls-data)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately MLS' are super restrictive with their data, and only allow agents and brokers that belong to the MLS to display their data, or they'll strike deals with large national 
sites like Zillow, HomeFinder.com, Trulia, etc. to show their listings.   There's no API where you can grab MLS' data if you're a random third party.   If your client is an agent or broker, you should be able to get data access right from their MLS'.   https://github.com/Placester/ruby-rets is a good ruby library if they use the RETS standard.

Answer (score 1):

If this is for your client and they are a registered broker or realtor, you may be able to get access on their behalf. [Spark api](http://sparkplatform.com/docs/overview/api) can help develop an api for you. You would register as a developer and use your client's name and mls information. I don't know if this is a free service or not, I see no pricing on their website. I will update as I know more.

I am doing the same thing. I have a client who is a broker and wants listings on her website.